# rake db:migrate syntax error when trying to do migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, syntax-error, database-migration

I get this error when I try to do rake db:migrate:

```
rake aborted!
/Users/farhadam/mboddy/db/migrate/20131113032404_create_microposts.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...t:prepareclass CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
...                               ^
/Users/farhadam/mboddy/db/migrate/20131113032404_create_microposts.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:718:in `load_migration'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:714:in `migration'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:708:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1012:in `use_transaction?'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1004:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:958:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:920:in `block in migrate'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `each'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `migrate'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:764:in `up'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:742:in `migrate'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/farhadam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my migrate table:

```
bundle exec rake test:prepare
class CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :microposts do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.integer :user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :microposts,[:user_id,:created_at]
  end
end
```

Anyone knows why this is happening and how I can fix it so that when I do migration it does not give me this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all this from the start of your migration file: `bundle exec rake test:prepare`

`bundle exec rake test:prepare` is run from the command line. Broken down, [`bundle exec`](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-exec.1.html) executes a script in the context of the current bundle; `rake test:prepare` (or more likely, [*`rake db:test:prepare`*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#rake-tasks-for-running-your-tests)) is the rake task to be executed.

Your migration should read as follows:

```
class CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :microposts do |t|
            t.string :content
            t.integer :user_id
            t.timestamps
        end
        add_index :microposts,[:user_id,:created_at]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`bundle exec rake test:prepare` is not Ruby - it should not be in your migration file.